# Como mostrar um thumbnail de um post wodpress em forma circular?

Tags: php, wordpress, css3

Estou tentando mostrar a imagem do post *wordpress* em forma arredondada, qual seria a melhor maneira? Ela é retornada através da função "the_post_thumbnail()" *wordpress*. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<?php
 $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=2&order=DESC&orderby=date');
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :
 setup_postdata($post);
 ?>

 <?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "2") { break; } else { ?>
 <div class="post">
     <div class="imgwrap">
         <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Usa border-radius do css man... igual o maninho de baixo citou.

Answer (score 5):

Através de **CSS**.
Se você tiver permissão de usar o arquivo, altere a class `imgwrap` que envolve a imagem.

Coloque um:

```
.imgwrap{
     border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver, apliquei sua dica diretamente no _img_, obrigado.

Comment: Isso aí. Se fosse na `div`, esqueci de dizer que era preciso colocar um `overflow:hidden`.